# How to make GDB verbose about its solib search process

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble making GDB load a particular library as a replacement for a library used in a core file.

How can I make so GDB list which paths it tries for each library? Something like `set debug auto-load on`, but for shared libraries.

Comment: Like [`set debug solib on`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Debugging-Output.html)?

Comment: This option will be available only in ongoing release of GDB 13 according to NEWS file https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having trouble making GDB load a particular library as a replacement for a library used in a core file.

GDB will look up *absolute* paths it obtains from the `core`.

Because of this, setting `solib-search-path` is ineffective, and only setting `sysroot` or `solib-absolute-prefix` is.

In addition, you need to set `sysroot` or `solib-absolute-prefix` *before* loading the `core`. That is, this works:

```
gdb -ex 'set sysroot /tmp/sysroot' -ex 'file a.out' -ex 'core core'
```

whereas this doesn't (`sysroot` setting happens *after* the file and `core` are already loaded):

```
gdb -ex 'set sysroot /tmp/sysroot` a.out core
```

> How can I make so GDB list which paths it tries for each library?

There doesn't appear to be such an option. In particular, `set debug solib on` doesn't actually help here. Using trunk GDB:

```
gdb/gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 14.0.50.20230115-git
...
(gdb) set debug solib on
(gdb) file /tmp/a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...
(gdb) core /tmp/core
[New LWP 29158]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000401116 in main () at crash.c:3
3         return *ip;
(gdb)
```

You can determine where GDB is looking for shared libraries by running it under `strace`:

```
strace -e open,openat -o /tmp/strace.out  gdb/gdb -ex quit /tmp/a.out /tmp/core
```

In `/tmp/strace.out`:

```
...
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29289, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY) = 9
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/core", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 10
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY) = 10
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 11
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 11
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 11
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 12
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
...
```